# I have no idea whats wrong with the if statement

Tags: python-3.x, multiplication

I'm making a simple 'if' statement to check if the answer the user gave to a multiplication sum was correct, and have the code print "correct" or "wrong". However I cant understand why the code keeps returning wrong even when I return the correct answer.

Here is the code.

```
print("what is 2 x 10")
answer = 2 * 10
user_answer=input("answer: ")

if answer == user_answer:
    print("correct")
else:
    print("wrong")
    print(f"the answer was {answer}")
```

Comment: The input is a string, you compare an int (2*10) with a string ("20"). Convert the input to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user_answer = int(input("answer: "))`

To fix this bug, you need to convert the user's input to an integer using the int() function before comparing it with answer.